# Are Eilenberg-MacLane spectra finite?

Tags: stable-homotopy

Let $A$ be a finite abelian group. Can $HA$, the Eilenberg-MacLane spectrum, be written as a finite colimit built of the sphere spectrum? It seems like "no" because one must kill off all higher stable homotopy groups of spheres, but I'm new to stable homotopy theory.

Comment: A finite spectrum has finite dimensional mod p homology for all primes. On the other hand, if A has p-torsion, the mod p homology of $HA$ will be infinite dimensional. For instance the mod p homology of $H\mathbb{Z}/p$ is the dual Steenrod algebra. So the answer is no.

Comment: To elaborate: Since $H_0(HA)=\pi_0(HA)=A$, you will need $A$ to be a finitely generated abelian group. So we have $A=Z^{⊕r}⊕⨁_i Z/p_i^i$. If there is p-torsion for some prime p, proceed as in the comment by Geoffroy Horel, otherwise you use the fact that $H^*(HZ;F_2)=A^*/Sq^1$, where $A^*$ is the mod 2 Steenrod algebra, to conclude that it is impossible.

Comment: Is the reason that a finite spectrum has finitely generated mod p homology because any finite colimit can be turned into a sequence of pushouts (in a stable oo-category), and Mayer-Vietoris puts a bound on the homology groups of these pushouts? Or is there something special about "mod p" as well?

Comment: @JeanBatiste You can simply use Mayer-Vietoris to see that the category of spectra with finitely generated homology is closed under (homotopy) pushouts. There's nothing special about mod p homology, except that the computations of the homology of Eilenberg-MacLane spectra is easier if you have coefficients in a field.

Comment: @GeoffroyHorel: why not make your comment an answer?